# how to get a more detailed script error from require.js in LogCat

Tags: cordova, requirejs, logcat

Requirejs is prints only a generic script error to LogCat when debugging my PhoneGap application. How can I get more details to locate the error? Stack trace?

```
"Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/require.js (1746)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an override of the [global requirejs onError](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#requirejsonerror) function. [JSON.prune](https://github.com/Canop/JSON.prune) also proved useful in debugging (the error object returned in circular)